# visual studio - gives blank screen as output

Tags: c++, dll

it shows.....

```
'2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ig7icd32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'2.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll'
'2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'2.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll'
'2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'2.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll'
The program '[7212] 2.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

how to solve this!!!!!

Comment: Are you using avast antivirus?

Comment: @NathanOliver nope..

Comment: Does this happen to a hello world program?  If not can you create a [mcve]?

Comment: @NathanOliver i tried so many.. its d same fr hello world prgm too!

Comment: What is actually the question or do we have to guess?

Comment: Does this occur before `main` or at the end of the program?  Use the debugger.  Set break point at `main` then single step each instruction (press F10).

Comment: @ThomasMatthews it builds successfully... wen i debug.. i get this and blank output screen...

Comment: Please **edit** your post with a minimal program that reproduces the issue.  Many people have Visual Studio (in different versions).  Make the program easy to copy to clipboard so people can try to recreate.  See [MCVE].

Answer (score -2):

Did you try simply reinstalling the program and restarting your computer? Worth giving a shot.